# jQuery dialog can not call second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

`IE v11` on `windows 10` using `jQuery v2.2.2` and `jQuery-ui v1.10.0`
Can't get a dialog to open a second time. I was having trouble getting the ok button to close the dialog and solved that by getting a reference to the dialog with the 'PDdialog = '. Now on the second attempt I get error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'. I even tried adding the .remove() in the Ok function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

  $( ".pnopener" ).on( "click", function() {
    var pn = $(this).text();
    var tag = $("<div id='pd-dialog' title='PN Details'></div>");

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'ajax/PNDetails.php?pn=' + pn ,
      success: function (data) {
        PDdialog = tag.html(data).dialog({
          resizable: true,
          height: 600,
          width: 750,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              PDdialog.dialog( "close" );
              $( ".pd-dialog" ).remove();
            }
          }
        }).dialog('open');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

and just for clarity here is the calling html:

```
<span class="pnopener" style="color: darkorange;">[Changing string]</span>
```

This is in a table td.

more:
In Firefox the error is: TypeError: tag.html(...).dialog is not a function

Thanks!!

Comment: It's already a dialog, so you can't re-initialize it as a dialog the second time. Either make the dialog before the click or destroy it after it's been used.

Comment: Also the error suggests that jQuery UI is not loaded.